# The dual of a circular cone

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis, inner-products, dual-cone, convex-cone

In my studies of cones and convexity I have recently come across the following unexplained piece of information presented:

> We consider a Euclidean space $ R^d $ for $ d \geq 1 $ we look at the circular cone for a unit vector $ u \in R^d $ and an angle $ 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} $ we define the circular cone as usual $ K = K_{u,\theta}=\{x \in R^d | \langle x,u \rangle \geq \|x\|\cos{\theta} \} $. We define the dual of a convex cone $K$ to be defined as follows: $ K^*= \{ y | \forall x \in S : \langle y,x \rangle \geq 0  \} $
>   Now, the book (in my native language) presents these two facts as ordinary notes without proof:
>
> 1. $ {K_{u,\theta}}^*=K_{u, \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta} $
> 2. If L is a vector subspace (of the vector space the convex cones of ours are in) then we have: $ L^* = L^\perp $

I cannot seem to be able to write a formal proof for each of these two cases presented here and I would certainly appreciate help in proving these. I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Note that $$ K=K_{u,\theta}=\{x|\angle (u,x)\leq \theta \}
$$

And for $x\in K$, $$ \angle (x,y)\leq \angle (x,u)+\angle (u,y) \leq
\theta + \angle (u,y) $$ Hence $$ \angle (u,y) \leq
\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\Rightarrow x\cdot y\geq 0 $$

That is $$ K_{u,\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta} \subset K^\ast$$

In further for $\angle (u,y)>\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta $ consider a two
dimensional plane $$P=(u,w),\ w=\frac{y-y\cdot uu }{|y-y\cdot uu |}
$$

Then $$\cos\ \theta u-\sin\ \theta w\in K$$ $$ \angle (\cos\ \theta
u-\sin\ \theta w , y) > \frac{\pi}{2} $$ So $y$ is not in $K^\ast$ so that $K_{u,\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta} = K^\ast$

(2) $L$ is a subspace so that $$L=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^d | v\cdot
v_i=0,\ 1\leq i\leq m\} $$ for some unit vectors $v_i$ Note that
$L^\perp =(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$ In further $L^\perp\subset L^\ast$ If
$v=v_L+\sum_i c_iv_i$ for some $v_L\in L$, then $$ v\cdot (-v_L) < 0
$$ Hence $v$ is not in $L^\ast$ so that $L^\perp=L^\ast$

Comment: I think you have a mistake in (1) you showed both inclusions as the same direction and u for the P is already reserved for the unit vector

Comment: could you please explain how you obtained that $\angle (\cos\ \theta
u-\sin\ \theta w , y) > \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: And why $ \cos\ \theta u-\sin\ \theta w\in K $

Comment: First : Draw vectors $u,\ w$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is related to orientation  Second : note that $u\cdot (\cos\ \theta u-\sin\ \theta w)=\cos\ \theta $

Comment: thanks but what if I am in $ R^d $ for $d>2$ does this still work?

Comment: Yes $P$ is two-dimensional $subspace$

Comment: thanks I think I got it now but one last stupid question if u is a vector what sense do you make of $ \cos{\theta u} $ so you can arrive at $u\cdot (\cos\ \theta u-\sin\ \theta w)=\cos\ \theta$ because this seems non trivial

Comment: I can not understand your question $\cos\ \theta u$ is just multiplication of scalar and vector

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant $ \cos{\{u\theta\}} $ as opposed to the $(\cos{\theta})u$ you probably meant

Comment: You're right I mean $(\cos\ \theta)u$